PyObjectID getting converted to string when insterted to MongoDB
from typing import Any
from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic_core import core_schema


class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
    """To create a pydantic Object that validates bson ObjectID"""

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(cls, _source_type: Any, _handler: Any) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.json_or_python_schema(
            json_schema=core_schema.str_schema(),
            python_schema=core_schema.union_schema(
                [
                    core_schema.is_instance_schema(ObjectId),
                    core_schema.chain_schema(
                        [
                            core_schema.str_schema(),
                            core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(cls.validate),
                        ]
                    ),
                ]
            ),
            serialization=core_schema.plain_serializer_function_ser_schema(lambda x: str(x)),  # noqa W0108
        )

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value) -> ObjectId:
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(value):
            raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")
        return ObjectId(value)


class GoalRecordStored(BaseModel):
    """Goal Record Model."""

    player_id: PyObjectId = Field(..., validation_alias="Player ID")
    date: datetime = Field(validation_alias="Date")

I am trying to push the player_id as an ObjectId but cannot do so and it is being saved in MongoDB as a string and not ObjectId. How can I change this?
I tried a lot of changes to the class, but it did not help. I have been trying to push the player_id in different ways, but it always gets stored a string and not the way I want it.
